# How can i have an empty array in an array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm wondering how can I have something like this :  `array( [ [], [], [], [1, 0], [1], [3, 2], [4, 5], [5] ] )`
with numpy arrays?

I tried concatenate, append, vstack but nothing work, I always end with this message:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use `np.append()` But note that you need to pass the indices ina list like `[[1], [1, 2], []]` :

```
>>> a= np.array([[1], [1, 2], []], dtype=object)
>>> np.append(a,np.array([[],[22]]))
array([[1], [1, 2], [], [], [22]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: the problem is that i don't know when come the empty array so if I do this : np.append(a,np.array([[],[]])) I will get : 
array([[1], [1, 2], []], dtype=object)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array( [ [], [], [], [1, 0], [1], [3, 2], [4, 5], [5] ])
>>> a
array([[], [], [], [1, 0], [1], [3, 2], [4, 5], [5]], dtype=object)
>>>
>>> numpy.hstack([a,[1], [1, 2], []])
array([[], [], [], [1, 0], [1], [3, 2], [4, 5], [5], 1, 1, 2], dtype=object)
>>> numpy.hstack([a,[[1], [1, 2], []]])
array([[], [], [], [1, 0], [1], [3, 2], [4, 5], [5], [1], [1, 2], []], dtype=object)
>>> np.append(a,np.array([[],[22]]))
array([[1], [1, 2], [], [], [22]], dtype=object)
```

perhaps I dont understand what you are asking

Comment: he wants to add them to array !

Comment: I give an example of a possible result, but I use random data so I can't guess when I will get an empty array and I parse some data so  I add them one data by one data, that's why I talked about concatenate or append.

Comment: The problem is when I only want to put one empty arrays for example : np.hstack([a,[[]]]) doesn't work whereas numpy.hstack([a,[[1], [1, 2], []]]) work very well